# CSS Placing a Div with no contents on the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I want to create rectangles on my web page to replicate lasers. I have tried to put it at the bottom of the page:

```css
.laser {
  width: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-100%, -100%);
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class='laser' style='color: red; left: 10%; height: 200px;'></div>
<div class='laser' style='color: green; left: 20%; height: 150px;'></div>
```

but it does not show up on my screen. My best guess is that the div is aligned via the top left corner so the box is under the screen? Yet when I try to translate it nothing happens as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change color to background-color

```css
.laser {
  width: 5px;
  position: absolute;
 //transform: translate(-100%, -100%);
  bottom:0; 
}
```

```html
<div class='laser' style='background-color: red; left: 10%; height: 200px;'></div>
<div class='laser' style='background-color: green; left: 20%; height: 150px;'></div>
```

Comment: I can see the div now but it is floating on the middle of the screen, rather than being connected to the bottom.

Comment: comment out the transform in your css. snippet updated

Comment: Thanks, just for future reference, what does the '//' do in CSS?

Comment: actually it's technically incorrect but will work to comment out a line.  The right way is to use /* ....*/